Goldstein’s section 2.4 Extending Hamilton’s Principle to systems with constraints
Goldstein in section 2.4 starts with an equation that I can’t wrap my head around for extending Hamilton’s Principle to systems with constraints. The integrand in the action is the Lagrangian plus the sum of $\lambda_{\alpha} \times f_{\alpha}$?  $L$ has units of energy $(T-V)$. $\lambda$ is unitless. The $f_{\alpha}$ are constraint equations. The $f_{\alpha}$ don’t have units of energy. Aren’t we adding apples and oranges in this equation? How does this equation make sense?

Well, the logic is as follows. Usually the Lagrangian $\widetilde{L}=L+\lambda^{\alpha}f_{\alpha}$ has dimension of energy. (Let us for simplicity assume that this is the case.) If we are given a constraint function $f_{\alpha}$ of some dimension, then the corresponding Lagrange multiplier $\lambda^{\alpha}$ is assigned a dimension such that their product $\lambda^{\alpha}f_{\alpha}$ has dimension of energy for consistency.

Thank you, Qmechanic!  Very helpful.
